# Is the Java -XX:+UseParNewGC garbage collection option still buggy?

Tags: java, optimization, configuration, garbage-collection

The Java garbage collector can be configured with the `-XX:+UseParNewGC` [option](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqGCPauses). However, a couple of years ago, some claimed this option was buggy in corner cases. Some incidents have been opened too.

I can't find much recent information about this issue. Is this option still dangerous? Has it been solved? Does anyone use it in production? Can it still cause trouble?

Comment: I can confirm I use it in production for a Glassfish 3.1.1 installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your text alone it sounds that the option wasn't exactly *buggy* to begin with: it had some minor issues, unlikely to occur in any one specific setting.

For a long time, the Concurrent Mark and Sweep collector has been a very common choice for the Old Generation. By default, it works with the ParNewGC collector in the young generation. If there were any problems with it in the early days, they have been fixed a long time ago.